# Computed column in group by clause

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a computed column but do not know how to add the column to the group by

i.e.

```
SELECT Category, SUM(Actjan + Actfeb + Actmar) AS Q, 'Q1' as quater
FROM tbl 
GROUP BY Category, 'Q1' as quater
```

This is on SQL Server 2008 R2 - the error is

> Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not
>   an outer reference.

Comment: just found one way - change the computed column to str(COUNT('Q1')) + 'Q1' as quater so it is not needed in group by

Comment: The error says that you have a constant in group by. 'Q1' is a constant, repeating in each row, and group by it is not needed at all.

Comment: true, I was getting an error message but now I'm not. Must have been a different column, I reckon'

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to group by a constant (the example you have posted is not a computed column). The following should work exactly as required.

```
SELECT  Category,SUM(Actjan + Actfeb + Actmar) AS Q,'Q1' as quater
FROM tbl 
GROUP BY  Category
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the value of the column

```
...
GROUP BY Category, 'Q1'
```